# Why does DRF custom exception raise 500 instead of 202?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

exception

```
class CustomExcep(APIException):
    def __init__(self, obj):
    super(CustomExcep, self).__init__()
    self.obj = obj

status_code = 202
default_detail = 'This already exists.{}'.format(self.obj)
default_code = 'accepted'
```

in serializers

```
def duplicate_check(self):
    if Person.objects.filter(name=name, age=age).exists():
        raise CustomExcep('Person')
    return True
```

error:

```
<tr>
  <th>Exception Type:</th>
  <td>NameError</td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <th>Exception Value:</th>
  <td><pre>name &#39;self&#39; is not defined</pre></td>
</tr>
```

This results in a generic 500 error with no other information.
If I remove the **init** method and just raise CustomExcep without passing anything in, it returns 202 as expected.

Can I not use init for an exception class?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: You haven't called the super on `__init__`

When you raise an `APIException`, the dunder method `__str__` is called. Here are the declarations of `__init__` and `__str__` on the DRF class `APIException`:

```
class APIException(Exception):
    """
    Base class for REST framework exceptions.
    Subclasses should provide `.status_code` and `.default_detail` properties.
    """
    status_code = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    default_detail = _('A server error occurred.')
    default_code = 'error'

    def __init__(self, detail=None, code=None):
        if detail is None:
            detail = self.default_detail
        if code is None:
            code = self.default_code

        self.detail = _get_error_details(detail, code)

    def __str__(self):
        return six.text_type(self.detail)
```

As you can see, the init method sets the `self.detail` attribute, which is referenced by the `__str__`. The reason you are seeing a 500 error is because there is an Internal Server Error in your code; the `self.detail` is raising an `AttributeError`.

Change your code to:

```
class CustomExcep(APIException):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(CustomExcep, self).__init__()
        ... your code here
```

Or even better; define `CustomExcep` as follows:

```
class CustomExcep(APIException):
    default_code = 202
    default_detail = 'Instance already exists'
```

Few other issues:

- You are passing the string `'Person'` and not the object `'Person'` in your current implementation
- The signature of `__init__` in your class is different from the underlying signature of `__init__` in the `APIException` class.

#### Update for the second issue

You have an indendation issue in your code, this is how it should look:

```
class CustomExcep(APIException):
    status_code = 202
    default_detail = 'This already exists.{}'.format(self.obj)
    default_code = 'accepted'

    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(CustomExcep, self).__init__()
        self.obj = obj
```

`status_code`, `default_detail`, and `default_code` are class attributes, they need to be nested within the class declaration, by indentation.

Comment: I have updated the OP - I am getting obj is not defined error with 500 status.

Comment: Of course, your assignment is reversed. Instead of `self.obj = obj`, you are doing `obj = self.obj`. This will raise a `AttributeError`.

Comment: Please take a moment to debug errors by yourself before posting on SO :)

Comment: Can you post your full code again. How are you testing this? If you are using the django shell, please note that you need to exit and restart the django shell for code changes to reflect.

Comment: I am restarting the dev server and making a POST request

Comment: shoudn't super and self.obj be indented?

Comment: Yup; nice catch. Updated